# 2 the same page addresses in generated sitemap?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap

I tried different sitemap generators and they generate 2 data structures refering to the same webpage:
On  the beginning:

```
<url>
    <loc>http://pundaquit.republika.pl/</loc>

<url>
    <loc>http://pundaquit.republika.pl/index.html</loc>      
    <priority>0.6400</priority>
```

I think sitemap generator should recognize main webpage in a domain and produce only one `<url></url>` structure.
Should I delete one of `<url> </url>` structure and which one? Does anyone know sites which explain this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your `http://pundaquit.republika.pl/` and `http://pundaquit.republika.pl/index.html` pages are considered two unique pages to search engines. To correct this you can set a `canonical` attribute in your index file and Google will recognize that .pl/ is your main domain.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

After this remove the index.html location from your sitemap and resubmit the sitemap to Google and Bing.

Comment: OK. Thank You very much for ur precise advice. However what I notice so far, when I enter in Google Search: "site:pundaquit.republika.pl" index.html url is not doubled. I can see only one entry pundaquit.republika.pl/ which refers to index.html file.

Comment: After adding 'link rel="canonical" href="http://pundaquit.republika.pl/" ' element to the head section of my index.html site, http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ sitemap generator produced the same sitemap refering to index.html url twice - ".../" n "/index.html". However as I can understand "/index.html" entry in sitemap should be deleted.

Comment: I may be mistaking but the xml-sitemaps website may not account for the canonical attribute and simply generate a sitemap of every link it can find up to the 500 page limit. Yes I would delete the /index.html entry, and leave only `http://pundaquit.republika.pl/` as the first entry. Viewing your sitemap though it says you have an error on line 130 which is the two << `<image:caption>Capones Island<</image:caption>
`

Comment: OK. Thank U very much. When I'll generate more sitemap.xml in the future, I will always remove index file entry n leave .../ entry as I did in this situation. If in Google Search - site:"mywebsite" shows unique pages only, I think there is no need to use canonical element in index main file. Thank U for all help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Google Webmaster Tools will give "duplicate URLs" warnings about `http://example.com/` and `http://example.com/index.html` some tools like A1 Sitemap Generator defaults to consider it a duplicate and not include the latter URL. Anyhow, using canonical like suggested by others (or even better, a 301 HTTP permanent redirect) is the best solution.